# Docker + SSAS + Windows container communication

Tags: sql-server, docker, window, ssas

Docker + SSAS + Windows container communication

I have an application running in an IIS in a windows container.
I have a sql server DB in the same server, but outside of any container.
This is working fine, but now I added a cube in a SSAS service in the same sql server, but the app can´t connect with the SSAS...

Notes:

1. The firewall is disabled
2. SSAS is configured to accept EVERYONE connections
3. From the container I can make a telnet to the ip and port (I have ping too).

I have this error in the log, when the app try to connect to SSAS:

```
Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnectionException: The connection either timed out or was lost. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing conn
ction was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 e
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.IO.BufferedStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.DimeRecord.ForceRead(Stream stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 length)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.DimeRecord.ReadHeader()
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.DimeReader.ReadRecord()
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServi`enter code here`ces.AdomdClient.TcpStream.GetResponseDataType()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.XmlaClient.EndRequest()
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.XmlaClient.SendMessage(Boolean endReceivalIfException, Boolean readSession, Boolean readNamespaceCompatibility)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.XmlaClient.SupportsProperty(String propName)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.XmlaClient.Connect(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo, Boolean beginSession)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection.XmlaClientProvider.Connect(Boolean toIXMLA)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection.ConnectToXMLA(Boolean createSession, Boolean isHTTP)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection.Open()
   at Ors.Components.Pivot.Dapper.PivotDao`1.Connect(ExtendedCube cube, String connectionCustomData)
   at Ors.Components.Pivot.Dapper.PivotDao`1.LoadDimensions(ExtendedCube cube, XElement xml)
   at Ors.Components.Pivot.Dapper.PivotDao`1.LoadCubeConfiguration(ExtendedCube cube, Boolean reload)
   at Ors.Components.Pivot.Dapper.PivotDao`1.Load(Boolean force)
```